# Hide Single Chart All series Labels Except 1

Tags: excel, vba, charts, label, series

I have been trying to create a VBA code which hide all the Series Data Labels and visible Data Label for Single Series that is 4.

Any help will be appreciated. My below code is not perfect where the error is appear 1Object does not support the property or method`

```
With Sheet16
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).DataLabels
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).hide
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(2).hide
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(3).hide
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hide` is not a universal answer for not showing items.  For `Series` you use the following:

```
With Sheet16
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).DataLabels
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(4).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = False
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = False
.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart.SeriesCollection(3).HasDataLabels = False
End With
```

Comment: That's impressive Thank you. @Darrell H